# Listing TFS work item titles with project history

Tags: tfs, comments, workitem

We recently started using TFS and SCRUM with our work item backlog in TFS. This gives us the advantage of associating a work item with a changeset check-in.

Is it possible to include associated work item titles in the "View History" of an object?
The reason I want this is to avoid including the work item id in the check-in comment.

Comment: Are you using TFS+Git, if so you should state that as the WI linking works differently depending on whether you're using TFVC or Git.

Comment: I am using TFS without Git

Answer (score 0):

You can open the Work Item, go to All Links, and create a new link of type Changeset.

[image]

Comment: I am pretty sure you have misunderstood my question. I do not want to link a WI with a changeset. I want to have a nice view of my changesets listed together with the titles of their associated work items. I know there can be more than one WI associated with a changeset and I know that I can view the properties of a changeset and see its associated work items there, but that requires an extra click instead of having it as part of the View History list.